# iOS Unit Testing: Class is implemented in both

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode7, xctest

I'm building an iOS 9 App with Swift 2 and Xcode 7.

My app runs fine when deploying it to my phone but when I run any unit test, I get the following error message for a lot of classes:

`Class _TtC5<AppName>19<ClassName> is implemented in both /Users/<Username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<UUID>/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/<UUID</<AppName>.app/<AppName> and /Users/<Username>/<Path/To/Workspace>/DerivedData/<AppName>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<AppName>.xctest/<AppName>. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only add the test class to your test target and none of the iPhone app classes. Then simply import your app name as a module on top of your test class to get access to all app classes.

```
@testable import MyAppName
```

Comment: This just not working for me - I used "@import AppName;" - is the syntax different than this?

Comment: Had same warning for macOS unit tests. To fix, had to remove the files from the test target as mentioned - thanks. But "import MyAppName" did not work, instead had to use the "@testable" decorator as well  "@testable import MyAppName".

Comment: Correct, @testable is now a requirement. Added it.

Answer (score 4):

Duplicated class implementations while running the test suite: in my case, since the test target has a **host app**, you don’t need to link the third-party frameworks. I had to clean the "Other Linker Flags" (`OTHER_LDFLAGS`) from Build Settings because it was linking to all CocoaPods of the workspace.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Mundi is correct for some cases.

However, I experienced the same error and what was causing it is that the `libPods.a` file for Cocoa Pods was being linked in the app target and the test target.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error with an XCTest. Remember to select `Allow testing Host Application APIs`.

[image]

Then inside of `Build Phases` for your `XCTest Target` - like others have said - make sure you have zero files in `Compile Sources` that are already compiled in the `Host Application`.