# "Class X is implemented in both" when executing unit tests in a project that use Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I added a unit test target to an existing project that use Cocoapods.

When I started the tests it runs the iOS simulator and I had a bunch of warning on the Xcode's console:

> Class PodsDummy_Pods is implemented in both
>   /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/604372F1-E934-445C-B8F6-3D8C86AA8E41/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A1BCAE6-5127-4288-B0E7-15588A1C09D1/MyAPP..app/MyApp.
>   and
>   /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fzjqljiyaapspvaylhszcbkhtijd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppTests.xctest/MyAppTests.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

**This error message appears for each class contained in the pod used by my project.**

At the end the project throws an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

When I typed `bt` in the Xcode's console, there is like an infinite loop on this error:

> frame #130498: 0x000000012626e897
>   MyAppTests`___lldb_unnamed_function42$$MyAppTests + 135

Any suggestion?

Comment: I dont have an answer, but i assume you tried clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, I tried to hard clean and rebuild but I still have this problem.

Comment: did u get any solution to this?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127896/ios-unit-testing-class-is-implemented-in-both

Comment: Did you finally find an answer ? I just ran into that and it is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the solution to this problem ! On my side, I had this issue with my swift framework unit tests. My Podfile was looking like that :

```
def import_gtm
  send :pod, 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 5.0.8'
end

target 'MyFramework' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyFramework
  import_gtm
end

target 'MyFrameworkTests' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for testing
end
```

Eventhough my tests were executing correctly, I had tons of logs, just like OP. After reading on this [Github issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4626), I changed my Podfile for the following :

```
def import_gtm
  send :pod, 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 5.0.8'
end

target 'MyFramework' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyFramework
  import_gtm

  target 'MyFrameworkTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

I'm finally rid of all these warning logs ! Try to clean before rebuilding (cmd + alt + shift + K) or delete the DerivedData folder content :

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

I hope this helps !