# Class is implmented in both... One of the two will be used. Which one is defined

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have tried to find a solution to this problem, however either the solutions people have given have not worked, or they are not explained well enough for me to understand.

In this thread: [Class is implemented in both, One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932341/class-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-which-one-is-undefine)
The answer is that there may be duplicate frameworks however my Pods-[AppName].debug.xcconfig file only lists it once.

In this thread: [iOS Unit Testing: Class is implemented in both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127896/ios-unit-testing-class-is-implemented-in-both) I am confused on how to do it. If someone can explain to me more in-depth what the solution is, that would be great!

Any other information regarding a solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what are you asking, wang? need better explanation. also which class of yours is giving this problem and what have you tried? make it easy for us so we can help

Comment: @staticVoidMan I’m asking for a solution. Im using the BEMCheckBox class. I want a better explanation of the answer in thread 2. And i’ve tried the first thread.

Comment: Imho, if you describe your problem with details specific to your problem and **then** ask for an explanation, it would be alot better for you and the one answering.

Comment: @staticVoidMan Okay, in the second thread I have in my post, can you explain the answer more in-depth? It’s a little confusing to me.

Comment: Sure, let me take a look.

Comment: Ok, I tried but need more details. **1.** Please share the contents of your podfile. **2.** Are you creating your own library/framework or using one? **3.** Could you also share the contents of `Pods-[AppName].debug.xcconfig` (_You may sanitize the data with dummy names if required_)

Comment: @staticVoidMan would it be easier if we talked over skype or text or via some other communication platform?

Answer (score 0):

```
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Firebase'

    target 'MyAppTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end
```

Moving `target 'MyAppTests' do` inside `target 'MyApp' do` and inherit search paths helped me.